# Combinatorics: on the number of Celtic knots in an n × m frame

Tags: co.combinatorics

Everybody has seen a Celtic knot like the ones below.

Mathematically speaking  a rectangular Celtic knot of size $(n, m)$ may be built as:

We draw the boundaries of a $2n \times 2m$ rectangle .

Then we draw some barriers, which are horizontal or vertical segments whose starting, ending and crossing points all have integer even-sum coordinates.

Let $K_{n, m}$ be the number of Celtic knots of size $(n, m)$, two knots that differ only by rotations and reflections are considered the same.

Of course $K_{0, 0} = 1$, $K_{1, 1} = 1$, $K_{n, m} = K_{m, n}$.

I have been able to calculate $K_{1, n}$, but failed to calculate $K_{2, 2}$.

Any idea?

Explanation of the examples:
In #8 the green barrier starts at point $(0, 2)$ whose sum is even, and ends at point $(4, 2)$ whose sum is even. The orange barrier starts at point $(1, 1)$ whose sum is even and ends at point $(3, 1)$ whose sum is even.
In #18 the green barrier starts at point $(1, 3)$ whose sum is even, and ends at point $(3, 3)$ whose sum is even. The orange barriers start at point $(3, 1)$ whose sum is even and ends at point $(3, 3)$ whose sum is even.
In the third example, the green and the red barriers cross each other at point $(2, 3)$ whose sum is odd, hence not valid.

The 21 $K_{2, 2}$ I know:
[image: 1]

Examples of the construction:
[image: 2]

Celtic knots:
[image: 3]

Comment: Definition not clear to me. The knots in your linked picture – are they all $K_{2,2}$?

Comment: Have you tried typing *Celtic knots* into the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: Hi Gerry, no the knots in the image are at leasr (3 x 3) If you want I can post some (2 x 2). I will try to give a clearer solution with examples.

Comment: I've tried "Celtic" in OEIS : no answer, but $K_{1,n}$ is sequence A032120 (the definition of this sequence covers the way I proved the result), I will tell OEIS as soon as I find some more results.

Comment: I can't relate the image of the 21 $K_{2,2}$ to the definition. Most of them seem to have corners at points with an odd coordinate sum.

Comment: Hi Peter,  Have a look on the "examples of construction" file, if you want more examples just let me know which image bothers you and I'll post the corresponding barriers. The barriers are lines the knot cannot cross. Mathematically speaking, only the choice of the barriers is relevant, not the way we use it afterward to build the actual knot

Comment: Ok, I think I get an idea of what's going on, but I'm going to need to sit down at a computer and play around with the graphics to fully visualise it.

Comment: This is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm your $K_{2,2}$ count and have a formula for the number of the number of Celtic knots *without symmetry*.

Call a point $(x,y)$ even if $x+y$ is even, similarly for odd.  Each $2 \times 2$ square with odd corners (such as the one bounded by $(1,0)$, $(1,2)$, $(3,0)$, $(3,2)$ in your examples diagram) can contain a vertical segment, a horizontal segment, or neither, but not both.  These squares are independent of one another in terms of the segments.  For $K_{2,2}$, there are four of these squares, so there are $3^4 = 81$ possible combinations of barriers without accounting for symmetry.  For general $K_{m,n}$, this quantity is $3^{mn-m-n}$.

In the $2 \times 2$ case, the 21 symmetry classes each have size 1, 2, 4, or 8 with the connection $$3\cdot1 + 3\cdot2 + 12 \cdot4 + 3\cdot8 = 81.$$  Computations for $K_{2,n}$ with $n \ge 3$ will have less symmetry (no 90 degree rotations or diagonal reflections), so I think symmetry class sizes are only 1, 2, or 4.

---

Edit: Actually, this is a classic Burnside's lemma kind of problem (a result known by many names).  For $K_{n,n}$ the symmetry group is the dihedral group of the square: identity, rotations through 90, 180, and 270 degrees, and 4 reflections, horizontal, vertical, the two diagonals.  The number of states fixed by the actions in the following computation are in that order:
$$ \frac{3^4 + 3^1 + 3^2 + 3^1 + 3^3 + 3^3 + 3^2 + 3^2}{8} = 21.$$
I think that approach gives $K_{3,3} = 67{,}257$.

For $m \ne n$, the symmetry group has four elements: identity, 180 degree rotation, and horizontal and vertical reflections.  For the next case I get
$$K_{2,3} = \frac{3^7 + 3^4 + 3^5 + 3^4}{4} = 648.$$
Looking towards a general $K_{2,n}$ formula, I think it breaks into cases for $n$ odd or even.  Next I get
$$K_{2,4} = \frac{3^{10} + 3^5 + 3^7 + 3^6}{4} = 15{,}552.$$
These two approaches should lead to formulas for all $K_{m,n}$ (I've worked something out for $K_{2,n}$, the general square and strictly rectangular cases shouldn't be too much harder, although they may again be modifications based on parity).

Comment: Thanks Brian, I will think about this very good idea.

Comment: Hi Brian,
May I call you Santa ?

Comment: @Mediat Ha! I've gotten that before because of my beard.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brian, I've been able to solve the general problem.
I wrote a 9-page document to explain it all, unfortunately I cannot upload it here, so I give you the final results (the formulas could be written with just one formula but it would be a lot more confusing)

Non Square Celtic Knot

$\begin{array} {|c|r|l|}\hline
n \text{ even} / m \text{ even} & K_{(n, m)} = & \dfrac{3^{2nm - (n+m)} + 3^\frac{2nm - (n+m)}{2} + 3^\frac{2nm - m}{2} + 3^\frac{2nm - n}{2}}{4} \\ \hline
n \text{ even} / m \text{ odd} & K_{(n, m)} = & \dfrac{ 3^{2nm - (n+m)}+ 3^\frac{2nm - (n+m)+1}{2} +  3^\frac{2nm - m -1}{2} + 3^\frac{2nm - n}{2}}{4} \\ \hline
n \text{ odd} / m \text{ even} & K_{(n, m)} = & \dfrac{3^{2nm - (n+m)} + 3^\frac{2nm - (n+m)+1}{2} + 3^\frac{2nm - m}{2} + 3^\frac{2nm - n - 1}{2}}{4} \\ \hline
n \text{ odd} / m \text{ odd} & K_{(n, m)} = & \dfrac{ 3^{2nm - (n+m)} + 3^\frac{2nm - (n+m)}{2} + 3^\frac{2nm - m -1}{2} + 3^\frac{2nm - n - 1}{2}}{4} \\ \hline
\end{array}$

Square Celtic Knots

$\begin{array} {|c|r|l|}\hline
\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{8ex}n \text{ even}  & K_{(n, n)} = & K_{(n, n)} = \dfrac{3^{2n^2 - 2n} + 2*3^\frac{n(n-1)} {2} + 3*3^{n(n-1)} + 2*3^\frac{2n^2-n} {2}}{8}     \\ \hline
\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{8ex}n \text{ odd}   & K_{(n, n)} = & K_{(n, n)} = \dfrac{ 3^{2n^2 - 2n} + 2*3^\frac{n(n-1)} {2} + 3*3^{n(n-1)} + 2*3^\frac{2n^2-n-1} {2} }{8} \\ \hline
\end{array}$

Comment: You could probably consolidate the cases by using a floor function.

Comment: Yes I know but it becomes more confusing and less readable

Comment: For the square case it would remain readable